# CPU frequency capped

Tags: power-management, battery, cpu

My CPU works fine during 30 seconds then drops to 800MHz.
My BIOS does not have power management.
All my temps are OK: around 65° at max.
I read every forum posts on the subject, tried everything.
intel_powerclamp, acpi-cpufreq, governors, have no secret for me anymore.
I removed my battery. Did everything suggested.

Until I boot under Windows and saw that CPU frequency is capped under ubuntu **and** Win10.

Then I read that maybe it could come from my power charger.
Should I buy a new one out of desperation ?

Edit: What still is bugging me is that even when booting on battery, it still occurs. So can it really be my power charger ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a hardware issue. The capping is most likely due to thermal throttling. Maybe a sensor went haywire and reports alarming temps. The sensor must not necessarily be visible in the OS. 
Another cause could be a power supply problem.

Comment: All temps (including CPUs) are below 65°.

Comment: Then it is most likely a power problem.

Comment: What still is bugging me is that even when booting on battery, it still occurs. So can it really be my power charger ?

Comment: The way you describe it now, it is more likely that the internal power converter is dying. The power from the battery also goes through this component. If it dies, either with or without the wall charger plugged in, the power supplied to the system would be affected.